# SSH from Ubuntu to embedded linux

Tags: linux, ssh, ethernet, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm a beginner un networking.
I'm trying to connect an embedded linux to my Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS by Ethernet.

I have configured the embedded system to work with a static IP adress (192.168.9.119).

I've add an eth1 interface on my Ubuntu, and set static IP to 192.168.9.118.

The embedded linux is directly connected to my eth1 via ethernet, but it doesn't works.

My ifconfig :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:64:f8:7a:7a
      inet addr:192.168.200.58  Bcast:192.168.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::225:64ff:fef8:7a7a/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:339694 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:122045 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:81556483 (81.5 MB)  TX bytes:92889268 (92.8 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:ba:51:d2:9e
          inet addr:192.168.9.118  Bcast:192.168.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:baff:fe51:d29e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:66 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:132
          collisions:1122 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:4068 (4.0 KB)
          Interrupt:22 Base address:0xec00

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:82 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:82 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6696 (6.6 KB)  TX bytes:6696 (6.6 KB)
```

The ifconfig on the embedded device (don't care of eth0) :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:C2:D5:D3:3D
          inet addr:192.168.6.118  Bcast:192.168.6.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1974 (1.9 KiB)  TX bytes:2624 (2.5 KiB)
          Interrupt:13 Base address:0xc000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:C2:D5:D3:3E
          inet addr:192.168.9.119  Bcast:192.168.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:71 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:10905 (10.6 KiB)  TX bytes:7773 (7.5 KiB)
          Interrupt:13

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

SSH error message (I think it's useless to you but I put it anyway) :

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.9.119 port 22: No route to host
```

Have you any idea on whats wrong ? Thanks

EDIT: Is this normal ?

```
user@linux:~$ ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
No data available
```

route -n (on embedded device) :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.6.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.9.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.6.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

And now, arp -n and route -n on Ubuntu :

```
user@linux:~$ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.200.120          ether   b8:ac:6f:b5:90:61   C                     eth0

user@linux:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.200.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.9.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: what is the output of "ifconfig" on the embedded device ?

Comment: I've edited my post with it.

Comment: there are packets counted in RX and TX. can you ping from .118 to .119 and vice versa ? if not, what is the output of "arp -n" and "route -n" ?

Comment: I've add route -n. arp -n doesn't exist on this linux.

Comment: the ping does not work ? what is "arp -n" and "route -n" on ubuntu ? join chatroom "embedded" if you like to chat

Comment: No, the ping doens't work : host unreachable. I've edited my post again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the cabling yourself? It looks like you have a cabling issue on `eth1`

```
collisions:1122
```

Comment: Yes I did, but the cabling is one ethernet cable from my eth1 to my embedded system. It's hard to fail that. Can it be my embedded system who need to be connected with a crossover cable ?

Comment: I would imagine a crossover cable is a must. Your config shows `TX bytes:4068 (4.0 KB)` which means it's transmitting something, but `RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)` means it isn't receiving anything.

Comment: I'll try with a crossover cable ASAP, and keep you informed. Thanks.